# Odoo statusbar widget for project.project

Tags: odoo, odoo-12

i'm trying to add a field to define statuses of `project.project` like:

```py
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from odoo import api, fields, models
class Project(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'project.project'
    _name = 'project.project'

    state = fields.Selection(
        [('open', 'Open'), ('closed', 'Closed'), ('sleep', 'Sleep')],
        string='Status',
        default='open'
    )
```

Add added to the view in a heritage:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<odoo>
  <record id="edit_project" model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="name">project.project.form</field>
    <field name="model">project.project</field>
    <field name="inherit_id" ref="project.edit_project"/>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
      <xpath expr="//header" position="inside">
        <field name="state" widget="statusbar" statusbar_visible="open,closed,sleep" />
      </xpath>
    </field>
  </record>
</odoo>
```

But the field is displayed like a span in the header.

[image: Bad widget statusbar project.project]

I tried everything described in the documentation and in base of other usages but with this in particular is not working and i don't know why. Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, after trying everything for some ultra strange reason it work with no change.

[image]